# Revolution Slider not working on my Unify themes (bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, unify, revolution-slider

Did anyone know why its my revolution slider is not working ? My images was not found when I uploaded to  server . But its go fine in offline . 
Here my link :  http://cloudsblack.info/

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file names are case sensitive in linux server.

i.e cover_01.jpg  Vs Cover_01.JPG

Please take a look carefully the difference between these names.
Also check the following directory that the images are uploaded successfully with correct name.

http://cloudsblack.info/assets/img/sliders/revolution/cover_01.jpg

Comment: HI Ahmad Sharif , its works ! Thanks you so much for your help =D